# Unable to install CVXR package due to gmp installation

Tags: r, gmp, mpfr

I'm attempting to use the 'CVXR' package for optimization problems, but need to have the 'gmp' package installed first, which fails to install.

When I attempt to install 'gmp' using install.packages("gmp"), I receive the below error:

> configure: error: Header file gmp.h not found; maybe use --with-gmp-include=INCLUDE_PATH
> ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘gmp’

This error prompted me to look through the 'gmp' download available at https://gmplib.org/, but could not locate the gmp.h header file noted above.

I am trying to install this in my R Studio server environment. Curiously enough, I was able to successfully install both 'gmp' and 'CVXR' on my local machine without an issue. This prompted me to look through the 'gmp' files that were installed on the local machine. I could not locate gmp.h there either. I tried to simply copy the files of that installation over to my server environment and run library('gmp'), but that was again unsuccessful and produced the below error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gmp’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
> shared object ‘gmp.so’ not found